# Can I get QT 4 applications to work with HiDPI?

Tags: qt

Lots of programs are working for me now with HiDPI, but there are still lots of programs that don't, like Mendeley Desktop (QT4, I think), and Okular (also QT, I believe). The icons are tiny, and many UI elements are unusable. I'd love to get these working. Is there a way to set a scaling factor in QT 4, like via the command line?